# show multiple rows for each result value

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables one for products and another for items.
I want to show all items details for each product in one table like this:

[image]

I have tried to make a nested while loops but the result not as I want.

```
        <table border="1">
            <thead>
                <th>Product No.</th>
                <th>Product Name</th>
                <th>T.Qty</th>
                <th>Item No.</th>
                <th>Item Name</th>
                <th>Qty </th>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
               <tr>
                    <td><?php echo $Product_no ?></td> 
                    <td><?php echo $Product_name?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $TQty ?></td>

              <?php
                      // my problem is here
                       $Items= $connect->prepare("Query Statment?");
                       $Items->execute();
                       $res = $Items->get_result();
                       while($GetItems = $res->fetch_assoc()){
               ?>
                         <td><?php echo GetItems['Item_no'];?></td> 
                         <td><?php echo GetItems['Item_name']; ?></td>
                         <td><?php echo GetItems['Qty']; ?></td>
                    <?php } ?>
                </tr> 
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

but the items displayed beside each other not below.

Comment: Can you change the query? If can, show it to us.

Comment: sure, if it can give me the output needed.

Comment: @esqew First dont need to be rude. If he knew how to do it he wont be asking. Also you need more than `<tr></tr>` to nest the result.

Comment: By "beside each other", do you mean the product 1 table is next to the product 2 table? You mentioned a nested while, but your example looks like it only show the inner one. ...you're probably better off with a single query, ordered appropriately, and no nested loop. Just loop over the results and generate empty `<td />` for the name, num, qty when they repeat.

Comment: I'm not sure in what part of the code the `$product_no` change. because right now looks like only print one row.

Comment: @Uueerdo I meant the items details shown beside each other. not separated rows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a problem in your html table code. You should close the  tag for each row you have, and, in case it is not the first line for that element, insert 3 cells with no data:

```
       <tbody>
           <tr>
                <td><?php echo $Product_no ?></td> 
                <td><?php echo $Product_name?></td>
                <td><?php echo $TQty ?></td>

          <?php
                  // my problem is here
                   $Items= $connect->prepare("Query Statment?");
                   $Items->execute();
                   $res = $Items->get_result();
                   $i=0;
                   while($GetItems = $res->fetch_assoc()){
                      if ($i!=0){
                          echo "<td></td><td></td><td></td>";
                      }
           ?>
                     <td><?php echo GetItems['Item_no'];?></td> 
                     <td><?php echo GetItems['Item_name']; ?></td>
                     <td><?php echo GetItems['Qty']; ?></td>
                <?php 
                     echo "</tr>";
                     $i++;
                } ?>

        </tbody>
```

Comment: Small nitpick, but you'll need to also echo a new opening `<tr>` when `$i != 0`